# Как хранят информацию потоки ввода-вывода?

Tags: java, кодировка, поток-ввода

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему при вводе в консоли, скажем, буквы ‘t’ и последующих выводах `System.in.read()` и `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).read()`, получается один и тот же результат при приведении к типу `int`, а именно: 116. Ведь стандартный read() байтового потока должен читать по одному байту, и выдать ноль (как первый байт двухбайтной записи ‘t’), а символьный BufferedReader всё выдаёт правильно.
В чём дело?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Консоль передает готовые байты.

`System.in` — это входной поток процесса Java, который управляется ОС. Консоль передает в этот поток уже преобразованные байты.

Что происходит когда Вы вводите данные в консоли:

- Консоль преобразовывает введенные символы в байты в соотвествии с кодировкой заданной для консоли.
  Установка кодировки зависит от отдельно взятой консоли/ОС.
  Скорее всего в Вашей консоли установлена кодировка, которая преобразовывает `t` в один байт.
- `System.in.read` честно считывает полученный байт.
- [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/InputStreamReader.html) преобразовывает полученные байты в символы в соответствии с кодировкой по-умолчанию, т.к. Вы выбрали конструктор с незаданой кодировкой. Кодировка по-умолчанию задается параметрами JVM.
  Можете проверить кодировку Вашего reader-а следующим кодом:

  ```
      InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
      System.out.println("Encoding: "+reader.getEncoding());
  ```

  Кодировку можно задать явно, воспользовавшись одним из конструкторов.
  При считывании reader считывает байты из входного потока и преобразовывает их в соответствии с кодировкой в числовое значение соответствующего символа (char). Согласно спецификации Java ([§3.1 Unicode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1)), символы хранятся в кодировке UTF-16.
  Допустим мы используем однобайтную кодировку, вводим символ «ы» и обрабатываем его:

  ```
      char value = (char) reader.read();
  ```

  Reader прочитает из входного потока один байт, поймет что это за символ  найдет этот символ в таблиц UTF-16 и вернет его числовое значение. В резултате этот код будет эквивалентен:

  ```
     char value = 'ы';
  ```

  независимо от кодировки.

### Двухбайтные кодировки

Чтобы увидеть двухбайтное кодирование стандартного ввода нужно установить соответствующую кодировку. В целях экономии места символы английского алфавита в большинстве кодировок кодируются одним байтом.

> ... должен читать по одному байту, и выдать ноль (как первый бит двухбитной записи ‘t’)

Так символы преобразовываются в двухбайтных кодировках с [порядком от старшего к младшему](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D1%82_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BA_%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83) (например, UTF16-BE). Соответственно, чтобы увидеть такое преобразование через `System.in.read` Вам нужно подавать данные на вход в такой кодировке.

Это можно сделать рядом способов, например:

1. Прочитать документацию консоли, узнать как задать для нее кодировку и поддерживается ли кодировка UTF16-BE. Если да, то задать кодировку. Если нет, то этот способ не подойдет.
2. Не вводить данные с консоли, а передать на вход файл с текстом. Файл сохранить в кодировке UTF16-BE, после чего выполнить команду вроде:

   ```
       java Main < encoded.txt
   ```

   Нужно принять во внимание, что при сохранении первым символом в файле будет [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) и пропустить его.

Comment: цитата: <<InputStreamReader преобразовывает полученные байты в символы в соответствии с кодировкой по-умолчанию. Кодировку можно задать явно.>> Пожалуйста, объясните подробнее, что это значит? Т.е. не смотря на то, что InputStreamReader символьный поток, и обещает вернуть `short` (0..65535) он будет читать 113? Его не смущает, что так он больше 255 никогда не прочтёт? И что тогда происходит с вводом в консоль буквы, скажем 'ы', кодировка однобайтовая, но как то InputStreamReader её достаёт в виде `int:`1099. Очень запутался. Помогите! Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Direct Расписал подробнее про `InputStreamReader`, проверьте. Если коротко: число (символ) `'ы'` в java всегда `'ы'` независимо от того откуда и из какой кодировки оно пришло.

Comment: Удивительное открытие: Cp1251. Т.е. я просто не смогу вставить в консоль символ какого нибудь бемоля из нотной грамоты. Хитрое и красивое решение в Java, о котором я не знал. Спасибо!

Comment: @Direct Пожалуйста! Кодировку `InputStreamReader` можно [задать любую](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-). Настройка консоли Windows может быть хитрее, посмотрите команду [`chcp`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp)

Comment: Да, тыкался с этой командой вчера :) не мог предугадать, что `InputSreamReader` не сплошной unicode =)

Answer (score 1):

При явном приведении строки к массиву байтов:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "t";
        byte[] b = str.getBytes();
        System.out.println(b.length); //длина массива
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b)); //значение
    }
}
```

увидим в консоли

```
1
[116]
```

Длина массива из строки `"t"` это 1, а искомый байт `116`.

Дейстивительно, как выше ответил @default locale, `read()` честно отдает этот байт.

P.S.

В случае с двубайтным символом, например `"ы"`, метод `getBytes()` дает массив из двух байт `[-47, -117]`, а если считывать этот символ из потока методом `System.in.read()`, мы получим тоже два байта 209 и 139. Почему так, потому что (цитирую из "Программирование на Java", Патрик Нимейер, Дэниэл Леук, 4-е издание 2014 г., стр.568 )

> на платформе Java для выделения конца потока данный метод использует
>   специальное значение, следуя стандарту из языка С. Байты возвращаются
>   в виде беззнаковых целых чисел в диапазоне от 0 до 255;

Закономерность смещения значения байтов простая - явное приведение `int` к `byte`.

`(byte) 209` и `(byte) 139` соответственно `-47` и `-117`.

В случае, если мы читаем методом `read()` из потока типа `BufferedReader`, то возвращаем кодировку символа, как сказано в документации:

> The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535
>   (0x00-0xffff)

Comment: `String.getBytes()` возвращает байты в кодировке по-умолчанию, которая задается для JVM. [209, 139] это представление «[ы](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm)» в [UTF-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Если будет установлена кодировка Windows-1251 (как у автора), то вернется один байт.

Comment: Первоначально было сложно понять, что именно вызвало трудности, поскольку в вопросе были некоторые неточности, которые вы исправили. Эти неточности касались понимания байтового (а не битового) представления символов в JVM.